# is it possible for git to track the ".git" folder?

Tags: git, recursion

I do work on the same projects on different computers, I was wondering if there is a way to track that .git folder so I won't have to reconfig the config file in all the local files.

I push all my work to bitbucket.

Comment: Yo dawg. I heard you liked source control so we put a .git in your .git so you can track while you track

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.

But you can store in git a text files with the 2 or 3 commands you use to reconfigure each repository. You can make it a `.sh` if it helps.